# VS2008 Express Editions and Resources

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resources

I am wanting to add resources (such as an icon) into a WinAPI based program in VC++ 2008 EE and am struggling.  As there is no resource editor bundled with the IDE, is it possible?

My Google searches all seem to related to C# or other managed environments.

Thanks all,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no resource editor with the Express Edition. (edit) I couldn't find a feature matrix on the official site, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_C.2B.2B_Express) says so, so it must be right;-)

You could look at 3rd party tools - a quick web search throws up [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/) as a possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a matrix which would explicitely state that EE hasn't such a feature but I also can't find it anymore.

Unfortunately you can't edit *.rc files graphically with Visual Studio 2008 EE.
Only "Standard Edition" and higher have a native resource-editor bundled.
With the Express Edition you can only edit windows forms via WYSIWYG.

As Steve Haigh said, you can build such a file with ResEdit or any other text editor and just add this generated/written file to your project.
VC2008EE will be able to compile the *.rc-file, despite the lack of a graphical editor.